# JQuery $.Post Method response

Tags: jquery, post

I am using Jquery to do POST to authenticate my page.

```
$.post("api/authenticate", {"authkey": authkey}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success === "false") {
    window.location="/Login.html";
    } 
});
```

EDIT!!

If authentication is unsuccessful, my php function will return a json object

```
{"success":"false"}
```

However, the console.log(data) does not return me anything. even though I can see the response in the resource.

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freon's answer probably works, here's an alternative, try forcing the `dataType` to JSON.

```
// This is the signature for $.post
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )

$.post("api/authenticate", {"authkey": authkey}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success === "false") {
        window.location="/Login.html";
    } 
}, "json");
```

Another think to look for is to make sure your server responds with a 2xx status. If you return a different status, `jQuery` will not try to read the response. It will instead look for status code handlers set in the `statusCode` option that is passed to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

## Example

```
jQuery.ajax( "api/authenticate", {
    data: {"authkey": authkey},
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: {
       306: function(jqXhr, errorType) {
            alert('Could not login')
            // If you still want to access the response, it's accessible as raw text
            // If it's JSON, you have to parse it.
            alert (jqXhr.responseText);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I realize function(data) is only entered when the api/authenticate is successful. Any idea what can I do to get the data when the api call is unsuccessful?

Comment: ahhh. i found out what was wrong. In my php function, even though i returned a json, i returned it with a page 306 error. Hence the post method rejected the response and deemed it unsuccessful. I am able to read the response now. Thank you!

Comment: @Wilson OK, since you accepted this answer, I'll add that information to the answer itself so it's more readily available for future users

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting a JSON, use $.getJSON. It'll parse your response as a JSON object.

```
$.getJSON("api/authenticate", {"authkey": authkey}, function(jsonObj){
    console.log(jsonObj);
    if (jsonObj.success === "false") {
       window.location="/Login.html";
    } 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: is $.getJson using the method get or post?

Comment: It uses GET. You can see more details at the link in answer.

Comment: Hmm. I can't. I need to use post. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to iterate through your data as an array e.g. `data[0]` via a for loop or a while loop

Comment: sorry. data[0] gives me "undefined"

Comment: console.log(data) returns a blank value. Even it is an array it shouldn't be empty.